# Hardware for time-gated signal

Tags: switches, pulse, hardware

[image]

Hey,

I am working on a design for an acoustic sensor,

I am applying an excitation field at a certain frequency (a) and recording the response of the sensor (b), however, for my application, I only need the ringdown part,

What is the most reliable way to get the gated response (c), I am aware that the switch should be synchronized to the excitation field pulse, but not sure how to build the hardware for that?

Thanks,

Comment: I wouldn't use a receive switch, I'd sample continuously, ideally synchronously with the excitation, and just discard the samples taken during the ring-up.

Comment: Does the ring-down part start exactly where the excitation pulse stops? In that case you could use a MOSFET (P-channel for example) as a gate for the ringing response, or the CD4066 IC (it is a "quad bilateral switch intended for the transmission or multiplexing of analog or digital signals"), synchronized to the excitation pulse generator.